# Add contacts to "where" field in Google Calendar entry

Tags: google-calendar, google-contacts

Say I have an event that takes place at one of my contact's, I'd like to add this contact to the "where" field of the event, so that e.g. Google Maps can display the appropriate address. Is this possible?

Note: The contact doesn't use Google apps at all, so adding him/her as a participant of the meeting is not an option.

Comment: As opposed to putting their address you mean?

Comment: Well, actually what I want is their address (because that's the place), but the rational for specifying the contact would be "I'm at X's place). The calendar could use X's address, then.

Comment: @jhwist: did you find my answer useful? Please give feedback if you need assistance with the implementation.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a small snippet that does the trick.

### Code

```
function CalendarEvents() {
  // get contact 
  var contactByMail = ContactsApp
    .getContactsByEmailAddress('e-mail with address in Google Contacts');

  // get location
  var location = contactByMail[0].getAddresses()[0].getAddress();

  // set date
  var date = new Date("September 26, 2013");

  // fetch calendar
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('e-mail of your calendar')
    .createAllDayEvent("test", date, {location:location});
}
```

### Usage

This code will run just from within the script. There's no need to add it to a Google Spreadsheet. Go to [script.google.com](http://script.google.com) while you're logged in. Add the code and press the bug button to authenticate the script. Afterwards, press the play button to execute the script.

### References

See the ContactsApp and the CalendarApp from Google Apps Script.

1. [CalendarApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/service_calendar)
2. [ContactsApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_contactsapp)

Comment: Asking as a newbie: How exactly can I use this? Where do I have to paste the code?

Comment: @David Moin, see my revised answer. Thanks for your feedback !!

Comment: When I try to debug the script I get the following Error: `TypeError: Cannot call method "getAddresses" of undefined. (line 7, file "Code")` What do I miss?

Comment: @David have you added an address of the e-mail contact?

Comment: Ah! No, I didn't. I have tried it out a little bit now... So I actually have to open the script every time I want to add an event?

Comment: @David it can handle one contact at a time, as what the OP asked for...

Comment: But I don't see the use in navigating to the script and entering the mail address everytime. That's not much better than navigating to contacts.google.com and copying the address from there.
I thought of a solution where you could simply do this from the event page.

Comment: @David well, be my guest to supply the code.

Comment: I didn't say that I could, but I think that is what the OP actually was looking for. Anything else would not make much sense.^^
Nevertheless - good work!